# ffmpeg - pause video after 1 second

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I use ffmpeg to create a video such that it pauses after 1 second but retains the full duration of the video? i.e. I am not looking to trim it. For example

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" pause=00:01:00 "output.mp4
```

I tried this from but it did not work. https://superuser.com/questions/1071369/ffmpeg-pause-video-every-10-seconds-for-3-seconds Any suggestions?

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -filter_complex \
       "[0:v]split=2[v0][v1]; \
        [v0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=1,loop=90:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[0v]; \
        [v1]trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=301,loop=90:1:299,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[1v]" \
       -map "[v]" "test.mp4"
```

Comment: if input has audio, you can overlay by this way: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:1[0v];[0:v][0v]overlay" out.mp4`